# acme.sh script failing with Verify error: Invalid response from https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/etc. Please add '--debug' or '--log'

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting, acme.sh

From time to time I run into this error when trying to get a Let's Encrypt certificate via the acme.sh script.

Sometimes it's the first time trying to get a Let's Encrypt certificate, and sometimes it worked previously but now suddenly doesn't work.

The error message is similar to:

```
domain.com:Verify error:Invalid response from https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/1kSTnls6_vcku98gwLEUMQNnbl1cSY1pdBrPi7sJdos
Please add '--debug' or '--log' to check more details.
See: https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/How-to-debug-acme.sh
```

Adding the `--debug` option, reveals some log entries similar to:

```
Changing owner/group of .well-known to username:nobody
chown: changing ownership of /home/path/to/example.com: Operation not permitted
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will save others some time googling, or poring over the documentation, or reading through the closed GitHub issues.

**First thing to check:** does the website folder have an `.htaccess` file in it?
*(By "website folder" we mean where the actual website files are stored, such as `/home/youruser/public_html/path_to_your_domain.com`*

*(Note that dot files like `.htaccess` are hidden by default in CPANEL file manager, so you might need to use an FTP app to check - or enable showing hidden files in the CPANEL file manager (there is a Settings button at top right))*

**If so:**

a) Rename the `.htaccess` file (to `.xxxhtaccess` or etc)

b) re-run the `acme.sh` script

c) When successful, rename the `.htaccess` file back again

Some References:

[acme.sh GitHub Issues](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/issues)

[acme.sh Documentation](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh#readme)